# flexbox - перенос блока на новую строку

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Как при маленьком экране (к примеру `max-width:480px`) сделать так, чтобы блок `отправить` переходил на новою строку?

```css
.input-group{
display:flex;
flex-direction: row;
}
.modal-form {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:flex;
}
.modal-input-text{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #e9ecef;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: .25rem;
}
.send-number {
    background-color: #BF4832;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    padding: 7px 10px 0px 10px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
        <div class="input-group mb-3 modal-input">
          <div class="input-group-prepend modal-form">
            <span class="input-group-text modal-input-text" id="basic-addon1">+380</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            <div class="send-number">Отправить</div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В .modal-form добавляем правило переноса элементов:

```
.modal-form {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Тогда, если во флексбокс не будет влезать его содержимое, то оно переедет на следующую строку. Для полной уверенности в переносе можно добавить @media запрос растягивающий кнопку на 100% по ширине от родителя:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .send-number {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Например  обернуть `input` и `span` в общий блок + задать `.modal-form { display: block; }` иди `.modal-form { flex-flow: column nowrap; }`:

```css
.input-group{
display:flex;
flex-direction: row;
}
.modal-form {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:flex;
}
.modal-input-text{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #e9ecef;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: .25rem;
}
.send-number {
    background-color: #BF4832;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    padding: 7px 10px 0px 10px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-form label {
  display: flex;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
  .modal-form {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="input-group-prepend modal-form">
    <label>
      <span class="input-group-text modal-input-text" id="basic-addon1">+380</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    </label>
    <div class="send-number">Отправить</div>
  </div>
```